# Morphing PHP driven site functionality into an Android App?

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, mobile

I'm completely new to Android DEV.

I want to make an app for a client that sells music, the idea is that it will be an alternate front end to the PHP site but will use some of the phone functionality such as locality etc.

Could anyone recommend the best approach to this?  Would I look at developing via the Android SDK or via Flex/Flash?  Is it possible to use php connections to retrieve dynamic data via android?

Any advice very gratefully received.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be developing your app using Android SDK as you can use all the available native features. From a Flex perspective, you have a limited set of existing android API functionality that is supported.

As long as your PHP backend supports all your HTTP requests, you are good with both Flex as well as Android way.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help, just wondering how many of the features I'd use - I'd only need the geographical data - so I wonder whether the phonegap/jqtouch option may be a better solution for me if it doesnt have any further disadvantages?

Comment: If you are sure about your requirements then choosing the platform to develop your app doesn't have any concerns(as long as they meet your criteria). It is totally your preference like how you would love to code.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you check out jQuery touch. It is a simple UI, but you get features like access to location (I believe through the html5 geolocation api (if they allow you to know their location))  and the list layout would work perfectly for purchasing music.

Obviously this is just my opinion. The Android API can be a little overwhelming at times but you will obviously have the most control over the phone and hardware, but jQuery touch keeps it simple. http://jqtouch.com

Comment: Thanks for your advice, so in theory I could just develop a version of the existing PHP site using jquery touch / Dreamweaver and then somehow convert this into an app?  Its the latter part of the equation I dont understand how to do without the API?